# $stateParams empty ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a state as such:

```
.state('home.deletemsg', {
  views: {
  "contentworker@": {
    url: '/delete/:entityname/:id/:redirectstate',
    templateUrl: "Scripts/proteanapp/templates/delete.html",
    controller: 'deletectrl',
    controllerAs: 'del',
    authenticate: true
   }
}
```

Then in the controller I have:

```
return app.controller('deletectrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams',  function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
        debugger;
        // check for ui router error
        var del = this;
        del.entityname = $stateParams.entityname;
        del.entityid = $stateParams.id;
    }]);
```

**Calling $state.go from a controller like :**

```
$state.go('home.deletemsg', { 'entityname': cd.Customer.Name, 'id': cd.Customer.CustomerID }, { 'location': false, 'notify': true });
```

But the `$stateParams` is empty, I don't understand why it is empty. I have tried putting an params object into the state and also resolve.

```
$stateParams.entityname //undefined

$stateParams.id //undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url` option should be present there on state definition directly, not inside `views` object of `state`. But even your controller should not have been called the way you have configured your state.

**Code**

```
.state('home.deletemsg', {
  //url should present here, rather than putting it inside `views`
  url: '/delete/:entityname/:id/:redirectstate',
  views: {
  "contentworker@": {
    templateUrl: "Scripts/proteanapp/templates/delete.html",
    controller: 'deletectrl',
    controllerAs: 'del',
    authenticate: true
   }
}
```

Comment: damn it, you are right. I dont know how i missed that :)

Comment: No worries, that happens. Even your controller should have get called..I feel  you are doing something else in you code